# Texture error when using glScale

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Im drawing using immediate mode in LWJGL to draw quads(yes I know its deprecated and VBO's are a better alternative) but when using glScaled to zoom in certain textures are cut off the bottom or the sides and a line is drawn above them. It is only visible when zoomed in and is more prevalent the farther zoomed All the images I use are made as a power of 2 i.e. 64 128 etc

Hopefully from this image you can see more clearly what I mean:

Texture Error Image
[image: Texture Error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot looks like the texture coordinate is wrapped.

Try calling `glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );` and same for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`. Or, depending on the OpenGL version, you might need `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` value instead, again, for both `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` texture parameters. The correct moment to set texture parameters is after `glActiveTexture` & `glBindTexture` but before `glBegin`.

You probably didn’t change these two parameters, the default for them is GL_REPEAT, and that’s what causes the artifact.

Comment: unfortunately trying both methods did not fix the error the texture error still persists

Comment: @MasonPacenta Do you render the complete texture in the quad, or part of a larger texture atlas?

Comment: The complete texture it is not part of a texture atlas

Comment: Then it’s probably an error in your texture.
Confirm the alpha value is exactly zero on the upper edge of the texture.
Also confirm the RGB values of completely transparent pixels is exactly black, see this article for how to optimize images for that, section “Dirty Transparency”: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/clever-png-optimization-techniques/

Comment: @Setlock If that won’t help, install https://renderdoc.org/ graphics debugger. It’ll take some time to learn but it’s very powerful tool to debug this type of rendering-related issues.

Comment: I have done all of those things however the texture error still remains

Comment: I fixed the error by moving the image up 1 pixel from the bottom

Comment: @Setlock In this case my original answer is correct, it’s texture coordinate wrapping around 0 :-) It’s strange glTexParameteri workaround didn’t work. Maybe you’ve called it at the wrong time, the right time is after glActiveTexture & glBindTexture and before glBegin. Or could be bugs in the Java GL wrapper you’re using.